# What's difference between 2 activities in manifest file?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Usually in `Android Manifest` file I see 2 ways to declare `activity` name:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">...
```

and

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">...
```

Two ways work well. However, I don't know what's difference in those ways! Can anyone explain it? And what's best practice to declare an `activity` in android? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

> However, I don't know what's difference in those ways!

There is no difference today. Both mean that `MyActivity` should exist in whatever Java package you have in the `package` attribute on the root `<manifest>` element.

> And what's best practice to declare an activity in android?

Either of those are fine.